# Reusable Bootstrap Modal with Conditional Event

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, modal-dialog, jscript

I have a problem about modal, first when i click the login button the modal will pop-up with ajax content, then when i click submit or forgot password from the ajax content inside of the modal, the modal keep closing. what i wanted is if i click *forgot* or *submit* the current modal still keep in open. i don't know how should i fix my problem , i hope someone help me.

**Clicking Login Button**:

```
<a class="dropdown-toggle" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#ActionModal" data-id="L" id="action">
                            <i class="icon-user-tie"></i> <span class="visible-xs-inline-block position-right"> </span>Login
                        </a>
```

I just use 1 modal with a `data-target="#ActionModal"` and use `data-id="L"`( ***L*** means Login , if **F** means Forgot) to make condition inside of this code:

```
                $(document).ready(function(){

                $(document).on('click', '#action', function(e)
                {
                  e.preventDefault();
                  // get the value of data-id of each clicked elements
                  var data_id = $(this).data('id');
                  // removing all content of selected id
                  var  action = data_id.slice(0,1);
                  var  id = data_id.slice(2);
                  console.log(data_id);


                  if (action == 'A') {
                    var mh = document.getElementById("modal_header");
                    mh.className = mh.className.replace(/\bbg-info\b/g, "");
                    mh.className = mh.className.replace(/\bbg-danger\b/g, "");
                    mh.classList.add("modal-header");
                    mh.classList.add("bg-success");
                    $('#modal-title').html('Add New Data');
                    $('#modal-loading').show();
                  }
                  else if (action == 'E'){
                    var mh = document.getElementById("modal_header");
                    mh.className = mh.className.replace(/\bbg-success\b/g, "");
                    mh.className = mh.className.replace(/\bbg-danger\b/g, "");
                    mh.classList.add("modal-header");
                    mh.classList.add("bg-info");
                    $('#modal-title').html('Edit This Data');
                    $('#modal-loading').show();
                  }
                  else if (action == 'D'){

                    var mh = document.getElementById("modal_header");
                    mh.className = mh.className.replace(/\bbg-success\b/g, "");
                    mh.className = mh.className.replace(/\bbg-info\b/g, "");
                    mh.classList.add("bg-danger");
                    $('#modal-title').html('Delete This Data');
                    $('#modal-loading').show();
                  }
                  else if (action == 'S'){
                    var x = document.getElementById("add-fName").innerHTML;
                     console.log(x);

                  }
                  else if (action == 'L') {
                    var mh = document.getElementById("modal_header");
                    mh.className = mh.className.replace(/\bbg-info\b/g, "");
                    mh.className = mh.className.replace(/\bbg-danger\b/g, "");
                    mh.classList.add("modal-header");
                    mh.classList.add("bg-success");
                    $('#modal-title').html('Login');
                    $('#modal-loading').show();
                  }
                  else if (action == 'F') {
                    // var mh = document.getElementById("modal_header");
                    // mh.className = mh.className.replace(/\bbg-info\b/g, "");
                    // mh.className = mh.className.replace(/\bbg-danger\b/g, "");
                    // mh.classList.add("modal-header");
                    // mh.classList.add("bg-success");
                    // $('#modal-title').html('Recovery');
                    // $('#modal-loading').show();
                  }
                  else{
                    $('#modal-title').html('Error');
                    $('#modal-loading').show();
                  }

                  $.ajax({
                    url: 'modal-data.php',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: 'data_id='+data_id,
                    dataType: 'html'
                  })
                  .done(function(success_data_fetch){
                      $('#modal-content').html('');  
                      $('#modal-content').html(success_data_fetch);  

                        $('#modal-loading').hide();




                  })
                  .fail(function(){
                    $('#target_div').html('<div class="panel-heading">Something went wrong</div><div class="panel-body"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></i> Something went wrong, Please try again...</div><div class="panel-footer"></div>');

                  });

                });
              });

                function submitForm(key){
                  var id = $("#id");
                  var fName = $("#fName");
                  var mName = $("#mName");
                  var lName = $("#lName");
                  var email = $("#email");
                  console.log(fName.val());
                  if (isNotEmpty(fName) && isNotEmpty(mName) && isNotEmpty(lName) && isNotEmpty(email)){
                    $.ajax({
                      url: 'data-process.php',
                      method: 'POST',
                      dataType: 'text',
                      data: {
                        key: key,
                        id: id.val(),
                        fName: fName.val(),
                        mName: mName.val(),
                        lName: lName.val(),
                        email: email.val()
                      },
                      success: function(response){
                        alert(response);
                        console.log(response);
                      }

                    });
                  }
                }
                function  isNotEmpty(caller){
                  if (caller.val() == '') {
                    caller.css('border','1px solid red');
                    return false;
                  }
                  else{
                    caller.css('border','');
                    return true;

                  }

                }
```

and also the modal i reuse:

```
<div id="ActionModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" >
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content login-form width-400">
            <!-- style="border-radius:  5px 5px 0px 0px;" -->
             <div class="modal-header" id="modal_header" >
               <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
               <h4 class="modal-title" id="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
             </div>
             <div class="modal-body">
               <div id="modal-loading"  style="display: none; text-align: center;">
                 <center>
                 <div class="loader"></div>
                 </center>
               </div>
               <div id="modal-content"></div>
             </div>
             <div class="modal-footer">
               <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
             </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```